# Setup codeblocks for opencv (How do I know I have the right files and libraries built?)

Tags: opencv, codeblocks

I (Win 7) followed [Alternative method, for OpenCV 2.2](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CodeBlocks) to configure codeblocks for opencv 2.4.4

I installed opencv and built it for my laptop using cmake. 
However, after many many days and many attempts I was unsuccessful. 
I extracted opencv 2.4.4 in `c:/opencv` and then `build` it in a folder I defined as`bin`. Bur, I do not seem to find the libraries and there are multiple include and opencv2 folder. It is very confusing. [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55687041/MyOpenCVTree.txt) is a file tree of my `c:/opencv/bin` folder. Sorry, if this is too much information. Also, my lib files has `.dll.a` extension not just `.dll`

When I run a sample code with opencv, it show error that opencv could not be found.

Please help me to do the configuration  correctly. You may post the list of files you have in your opencv folder? This is help me to know what do I expect.

You may use the following command if you wish.
DIR "Your OpenCV Dir" /B /S > "OutputFileDir\MyOpenCVTree.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, by Neol's help I could do it. 
I exactly followed his post [here](http://noelyahan.blogspot.com/2013/04/configure-opencv-in-codeblock-windows.html)

I was mistakenly thinking that vc10 (or vc9,vc11) can only be used when we need to use visual C++. (pardon my lack of knowledge).

I then added the dll files as shown in the post and the following figure.
[image]

At least the following "Hello World program" for opencv worked. (**Of course you need to change the image path or put an image inside the folder where the cpp code is saved**)

```
#include <highgui.h>

int main()
{
        IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("android.jpg");
        cvNamedWindow("Android", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("Android", img);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        cvReleaseImage(&img);
        cvDestroyWindow("Android");

}
```